# Удаление дублей в БД

Tags: mysql

Всем привет. Знаю, что тема заезженная, но решить поставленную задачу не смог.

Суть в чем:

Имеется таблица с перечнем фруктов/овощей которая имеет 4 поля (`ID`, `Name`, `List`, `Quantity`).

1. В поле `Name` заносится название фрукта/овоща.
2. В `List` состояние фрукта (зеленый, спелый, переспелый...)
3. В `Quantity` количество фрукта/овоща в наличии

Так, как у нас состояний несколько, поле `Name` может повторяться:

**Таблица №1**

```
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     id |   Name  |    List   | Quantity |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     1  | Яблоко  |  Зеленый  |    100   |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     2  | Яблоко  |  Спелый   |    40    |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     3  | Яблоко  | Переспелый|     3    |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Все было хорошо, но в один прекрасный день, что-то пошло не так, часть полей продублировались и получилось:

**Таблица №2**

```
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     id |   Name  |    List   | Quantity |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     1  | Яблоко  |  Зеленый  |    100   |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     2  | Яблоко  |  Спелый   |    40    |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     3  | Яблоко  | Переспелый|     3    |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     4  | Яблоко  |  Зеленый  |    100   |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     5  | Яблоко  |  Спелый   |    40    |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     6  | Яблоко  | Переспелый|     3    |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     7  | Яблоко  |  Зеленый  |    100   |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     8  | Яблоко  |  Спелый   |    40    |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
|     9  | Яблоко  | Переспелый|     3    |
+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Из за того, что поле `Name` не уникально, БД позволила создать дубликаты.

Теперь собственно вопрос, каким образом можно удалить задублированные поля `List` и `Quantity`, что бы получилось как в **Таблице №1** ?

Comment: сделать в другую таблицу `INSERT IGNORE INTO table` выбрав из этой все значения....... IGNORE говорит,что вставка дубля не будет произведена, при этом не будет прекращено выполнение работы INSERT.......... причем `INSERT-SELECT` можно сделать в одном запросе..... пример `INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1;` .......... и главное поля не забыть сделать UNIQUE  или PRIMARY_KEY  для дублирующихся полей

Comment: `Алексей Шиманский` Я не могу сделать `UNIQUE` так как значения Зеленый, Спелый, Переспелый могут повторяться

Comment: UNIQUE, как и PRIMARY_KEY  можно делать не одно поле, а несколько......`unique_index(\`user\`, \`email\`, \`address\`);` как пример

Answer (score 1):

Для начала удалите дубли в таблице:

```
DELETE t1
FROM tbl AS t1
INNER JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
            AND t1.List = t2.List
            AND t1.Quantity = t2.Quantity
            AND t1.id > t2.id;
```

`tbl` — имя вашей таблицы.

Во избежание таких ситуаций, сделайте составной уникальный индекс по полям `Name`, `List`, `Quantity`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON tbl (Name, List, Quantity);
```

`index_name` название индекса, а `tbl` ваша таблица.

Comment: Кстати MySQL хоть и собирается убрать ключевое слово 'ignore' но оно все еще работает. `alter ignore table tbl add unique index tbl (Name, List, Quantity)` не только создаст уникальный индекс, но и удалит все дубликаты автоматически